# c++ add a non-cpp (eg txt file) dependency for compile

Tags: c++, build

I am developing an application to "convert" a plain text file (with c/c++ like statements) to c++ stmts. How do I set a dependency to build this project only if there is a change to the text file. Eg.
route.txt generates route.cpp.
I want to create a dependency like this:
route.cpp: route.txt
route.o: main.cpp

Comment: it depends. which os? ide? version?

Comment: Both Windows (vs2012 IDE) and linux (gcc 4.6, make)

Comment: Make: add the text file to the build rules for it's dependents. eg pretty much exactly what you have: `route.cpp: route.txt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is different for each OS, IDE and version of IDE

for example:

**Visual Studio 10:**

(In other versions of VS it will be something similar)

add file to project, then right click on text file -> properties, select General in the tree, in the grid Exclude from build=No, Item type=Custom Build Tool, then click Apply.

there will be more item in the tree (in the left) called Custom Build Tool, edit the command line, better use macros like: `%(filename) %(fullpath) $(OutDir) $(SrcDir) $(ProjectDir)` etc.

I would add an empty file to the project as the target cpp, or generate hpp file to be included from a single cpp file.

**Makefile:**

You can add a build step like this:

```
<filename>.cpp: <filename>.txt
     command line to generate <filename>.cpp from <filename>.txt
```

again use the macroes: `$< $@ $>` you can echo each macro to see what it gives. You can also try $(input) $(inputs) $(output).

Comment: Thanks for the response, I did not follow the custom build tool part of the answer- What command to execute on the txt file and why.